# Encapsulating methods behind Getters

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm developing a website using the node.js/express stack and I'm trying to develop in the functional style which is pretty new to me. The express method [`res.send`](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L99) requires the function to be called as a method because it refers to `this` in the body, but calling methods doesn't work naturally in the functional style.

You can put the method behind a getter function that turns it into a function, but I don't know if there are any downsides to this other than code complexity?

Example:

```
(function() {
"use strict";

function Foo() {
  function bar() {
    console.log(this.x);
  }
  return {
    bar,
    get baz() {
      var s = this;
      return () => s.bar();
    }
  }
}

var a = new Foo();
a.x = 5;
a.bar();
a.baz();

var b = a.bar;
var c = a.baz;
//b(); // throws an error because `this` is not defined
c();

function wrapper(f) {
  f();
}

//wrapper(a.bar); // throws an error
wrapper(a.baz);

})();
```

Comment: Is your question here "Does encapsulating a function in a getter have any downsides aside from code complexity?"? If so, make sure you state it clear, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately it depends on your exact use-case, but adding wrapper functions is pretty typical in javascript and Node and is unlikely to add any downsides. You can fix the error you're seeing when calling `wrapper(a.bar); // throws an error` with the use of [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), as below:

`wrapper(a.bar.bind(a));`

Calling `bind` will ensure that `this` is set to appropriately when the function is called later.

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zuL9g98m/